# 3D Crossword, Cryptic, Statue View & Maze

Tags: grid-deduction, crosswords, mazes, cryptic-crosswords, three-dimensional

The following image depicts the layers of a $5\times5\times5$ cube. Using 3-dimensional thinking, can you find the way out of the cube?

> [image]
>   [Empty version with no crossword numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzG8y.png)
>   [Empty version with crossword only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdHHS.png)

**1. Crossword** (blue squares)

> **Across**
>   1. Separately
>   4. Hurry
>   7. Physical or online locations
>   10. Caesar's planet
>   13. Venomous snake
>   14. Milan cathedral
>   15. Plantagenets and Lancasters
>   18. Avoid, escape
>   19. Slim, smooth
>
> **Down**
>   1. Dumas character
>   2. Economic resource
>   3. Levels or makers of knots
>   10. Shy, fearful
>   11. Fictional Vietnam War veteran
>   12. Texas battle site
>   15. Clarinet, saxophone and others
>   16. A grave digger's tool or suit
>   17. Creep around
>
> **Away**
>   1. Place where bridehood ends
>   2. A hectare is 2.5 –
>   3. Streetcars
>   4. Man in Paris
>   5. Music sometimes played with one note
>   6. Use a rubber
>   7. Dr Pepper and Mountain Dew, for example
>   8. Recurring theme, motif
>   9. Share in a company

**2. Cryptic** (yellow squares)

> **Across**
>   7. Sticky substance from messy rupture (5)
>   8. No credit for one surrounded by debt (5)
>   11. Country to not get any introductions (5)
>   12. Small instrument making piece of furniture (5)
>
> **Down**
>   5. Instruments for speakers of falsehoods called out (5)
>   6. Plant lit up, put out (5)
>   9. Troops destroyed, having lost second city (5)
>   10. Some pig looks for place to live (5)
>
> **Away**
>   1. Piece of shiny long-lasting material (5)
>   2. Car infested with insects (5)
>   3. Airline is flying late after opening day (5)
>   4. Big boy misses opening of Golden Ox (5)

**3. Statue View** (red numbers)

> Insert the eight given 3D-tromino pieces (seven L-shaped, one I-shaped) into the cube. Pieces may be rotated in any direction. (Remember, these are 3D pieces so use the Z-axis as well!) The resulting space must satisfy the rules<sup>1</sup> of Statue View:
>   - Pieces cannot be adjacent to each other, but may touch at a corner.
>   - All unoccupied cells must be (orthogonally) connected.
>   - Any cells with red numbers must be unoccupied. These numbers give the total lengths of the runs of occupied cells starting immediately adjacent to the number, and extending outwards from it.
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> This puzzle type was invented by Deusovi and introduced in [Statue View: Tetrominoes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84335).</sub>

**4. Maze**

> Starting from the central square and treating occupied cells as walls, find the shortest way out.

The **final answer** is what was required in order to escape the cube (two words).

Comment: @wl Yeah, the Statue View should be possible to solve independently of the crossword parts. Where are you getting a contradiction?

Comment: @wl D'oh, I see what you mean. Correcting this now...

Comment: @wl Corrected now. (Found *another* error on the second layer as well.) Sorry about that.

Comment: @jafe Solvable now.

Comment: @jafe sorry my fault

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solutions to the first three parts:

> [image: crossword clues, cryptics, and logic explanations]

The maze:

> [image: maze solution] 
>   To escape, you need the **MASTER PLANS**.

Comment: Everything's correct. Nice job!

Comment: Ninjaed you by one minute! But your answer had all the details immediately, whereas mine took a couple more minutes to write them down. @jafe, up to you whether you go by first _answer_ or first _answer with all the details_...

Comment: Small correction I missed on first glance: One of the dark green pieces needs a rotation to fix the 3 in the bottom layer. You guys had the solution at pretty much the same time, but Deusovi posted a complete solution first so I have accepted this one. Great job, both of you!

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Crossword (blue squares)

> [image]

**Across**

```
1. Separately
```

> apart

```
4. Hurry
```

> haste

```
7. Physical or online locations
```

> sites

```
10. Caesar's planet
```

> terra?

```
13. Venomous snake
```

> mamba

```
14. Milan cathedral
```

> duomo

```
15. Plantagenets and Lancasters
```

> roses

```
18. Avoid, escape
```

> evade

```
19. Slim, smooth
```

> sleek?

**Down**

```
1. Dumas character
```

> athos

```
2. Economic resource
```

> asset

```
3. Levels or makers of knots
```

> tiers

```
10. Shy, fearful
```

> timid

```
11. Fictional Vietnam War veteran
```

> rambo

```
12. Texas battle site
15. Clarinet, saxophone and others
```

> reeds

```
16. A grave digger's tool or suit
```

> spade *[note: I have always thought this meant "a grave digger's suit" lol]*

```
17. Creep around
```

> sneak

**Away**

```
1. Place where bridehood ends
```

> altar

```
2. A hectare is 2.5 –
```

> acres

```
3. Streetcars
```

> trams

```
4. Man in Paris
5. Music sometimes played with one note
6. Use a rubber
```

> erase

```
7. Dr Pepper and Mountain Dew, for example
```

> sodas

```
8. Recurring theme, motif
```

> trope

```
9. Share in a company
```

> stock

Comment: Btw, the clue was "a grave digger's suit?" when first posted. I didn't like it when I reread the whole thing so I made an edit :)

Comment: thanks... is anything wrong here? @jafe

Comment: All correct so far!

Answer (score 5):

You need the

> MASTER PLANS.

Crosswords (Omega Krypton did a lot of these independently of me and probably earlier; I haven't looked at their answers) lead to these letters:

> ```
> A P A R T
> T N S B I
> H A S T E
> O D E B R
> S I T E S
>
> L L C T R
> S Y R U P
> O R A L R
> D E B I T
> O S R P T
>
> T E R R A
> I L A G L
> M A M B A
> I L B S M
> D U O M O
>
> A P E I M
> T O N G A
> M R B L S
> S T O O L
> A P P O C
>
> R O S E S
> E N P Y N
> E V A D E
> D A D N A
> S L E E K
> ```

Statue View solution:

> ```
> . . . . D
> . . 4 D D
> . H 1 . .
> . . . . .
> . . . . .
>
> . . 2 . 3
> . . A . .
>   H 5 B 2
> . . C . .
> . . C . .
>
> . . A . E
> . . A 2 .
> 1 H 8 B B
> . . C . .
> . . 2 . .
>
> . . . E E
> . . 3 . 1
> . 5 F . .
> . . 3 . G
> . . . . .
>
> . . . . .
> . . . . 2
> . F F 3 G
> . . . . G
> . . . . 2
> ```

Brief explanation (i.e., transcription of my notes while solving the Statue View):

> central 8 can only see 8 spaces, so fill them all
> 2 near it now has 2 blocks, so clear others
> 1 on middle layer sees what it needs, clear others
> 5 on second layer needs everything on the layer, so fill them in
> 2 on second layer now sees all the blocks it needs, so clear others
> we have a few L-pieces; name them and clear their neighbours
> 1 on top layer has only one candidate neighbour, so use it
> we've found the I-piece; name it and clear its neighbours
> 4 on top layer needs both neighbours there, so fill them in
> other 2 on second layer has what it needs, clear rest
> 3 on second layer has neighbours only top/bot, can't have 3 bot, so give 1+2
> found another L-piece, name and clear
> 1 on fourth layer has the neighbour it needs, clear others (actually already clear)
> blocks in NE on layers 3 and 4 need to make L-piece, only one way so do it
> 3 on fourth layer has what it needs, so clear others
> same for *other* 3 on fourth layer
> 5 on fourth layer has four neighbours, needs one more, only one way to do it
> found another L, name and clear
> now there is only one way to insert the final L, so do it

Maze solution by "flood-fill":

> ```
> 6 5 4 5 #
> 5 4 3 # #
> 6 # 2 3 4
> 5 4 3 4 5
> 6 5 4 5 6
>
> 7 6 5 6 7
> 6 5 # 7 6
> 7 # 1 # 5
> 6 5 # 5 6
> 7 6 # 6 7
>
> 8 7 # 7 #
> 7 6 # 8 7
> 8 # 0 # #
> 7 6 # 6 7
> 8 7 8 7 8
>
> 9 8 9 # #
> 8 9 A 9 8
> 9 A # A 9
> 8 9 A 9 #
> 9 8 9 8 9
>
> A 9 A B A
> 9 A B A 9
> A # # B #
> 9 A B A #
> A 9 A 9 A
> ```

This

> shows shortest distances from the starting cell; now we can work backwards from the end, finding the unique shortest path. It spells out MASTER PLANS.